# Approval workflow "request change" task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, tasks, approval-process

I have a query about the Approval workflow in SharePoint 2010.

When an Item is saved to the List, the request is updated to “in progress”. At this point, a Worklow Task is created. Users can then choose to “Approve”, “Reject”, “Cancel”, “Request Change” or “Reassign Task” . “Request Change” indicates that further edits are needed. A new task is created for the person you indicated and your task becomes completed. If this field is left blank, the change request will be sent to the person who started the workflow. However, at certain stages (serial users) in the workflow it would be possibly better if end-users do not get the option to specify whomever they want to request a change from OR that they can only select certain users.

Is it possible to let users only select certain groups/users? If so, how can this be done?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the task form using InfoPath.  From SharePoint designer, go to the Workflow's main settings page, then in the Forms section (bottom right) look for the Approval Task form (it might have a weird name like Approval_x0020_9 or something like that) and click on it.  This will open the form in InfoPath.

Change the view to ChangeRequest.  You will see a people picker control.  Right click on the control and then Properties.  In the SharePoint Server tab, add the url to your SharePoint site.  Then on the General tab, you can choose the SharePoint group that you want to restrict it to.